# Redirect page after site login with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, header

I am getting problem to redirect page after website login with facebook. 
1. On click of facebook login button from site it redirect to facebook login page
2. User get authenticate but it is not redirecting to next page given in `headrer('');`
3. If i refresh same page then it redirect to given location and url is looking like =">http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php/#*=*
4. It is working properly for [google.com](http://google.com) but not for local url and google url is looking like [incorrect google url](https://www.google.co.in/#_=_)
My code

```
if(isset($_GET['fb']))
{
   $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"."client_id=".$config['App_ID']."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($config['callback_url'])."&client_secret=".$config['App_Secret']."&code=".$_GET['code'];   
   $response = file_get_contents($token_url); 
   $params = null;
   parse_str($response, $params);

   $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$params['access_token'];
   $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));  //user data from facebook

   $email = $user->{'email'};    //i am getting email id from json data

   //search out for entry available for email in database
   $val_user = "SELECT email FROM tbl_facebook WHERE email ='".$email."'";
   $res_val_user = $con->query($val_user);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($res_val_user);
   // if not then insert data to database
   if($count==0)
   {
       $ins_fb = "INSERT INTO tbl_facebook set email='".$email."'";
       $res_fb = mysqli_query($con,$ins_fb);
       if($res_fb)
       {
          //echo "facebook data saved"; exit; //working for this   
          //header('Location:https://www.google.co.in/'); //working for this also
          header('Location:http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php');
       }
       else
       {
          echo "facebook data is not saved";
       }
   }
   else // if yes then redirect to welcome page
   {
        //echo "login successfully"; exit; // working for this also 
        header('Location:http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php');  // getting problem to redirect
        //header('Location:https://www.google.co.in/'); 
   } 
}
```

```
<?php
  // code for facebook login

 require 'lib/facebook/src/config.php';
 require 'lib/facebook/src/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $config['App_ID'],
      'secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
      'cookie' => true
));
?>
```

```
<a class="btn-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?php echo $config['App_ID']?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo $config['callback_url']?>&scope=email,user_likes,publish_stream">
                    <i class="icon-facebook icon-large"></i>
                    Signin with Facebook
                </a>
```

Comment: can u post the login script that u are using ?

Comment: login functionality working fine and i am getting user data from facebook but getting problem while redirecting

Comment: So its coming inside if(isset($_GET['fb'])){} and able to get the user data but header('Location:http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php'); does not work ?

Comment: yes if i write echo "something"; exit; then it show "something" but it is not redirecting header location

Comment: often its an issue of white space after php close tag, and echo somewhere. But to avoid that you can use JS redirect echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';

Comment: if i refresh same page while login it redirect to given url and gives url like "http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php#_=_"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45182/discussion-between-m-gaidhane-and-abhik-chakraborty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header redirect issues are often when there is a white space after the PHP close tag or before start tag, output before the header() etc.

To avoid this we need to make sure

- There is no white space as mentioned
- Do not echo anything before this.

In addition even if the header() does not work then add an exit() as

```
header('Location:http://192.1.1.1/mysite/welcome.php');
exit();
```

and finally you can use JS as

```
echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
exit;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use local path url do not use full URL

```
header("Location: welcome.php");
```